# Can we disable IPV4 and use purely IPV6 on Windows XP/2003?

Tags: windows-xp, ipv6

Is there any way we can use purely IPV6 on Windows XP or Server 2003. I know an IPV4/IPV6 dual stack exists in Windows XP, I just wanted to test whether only IPV6 can be used on XP. It is possible in Windows Vista onwards, but can it be done on XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows XP and Server 2003 share the same network stack (or at least major portions of it) which has some experimental IPv6 support, but not enough to use in production. Certainly not as a server. A few of the limitations:

- ***no DNS resolving over IPv6***
- no IPv6 firewall
- not all applications use IPv6
- you can't configure addresses manually (important for servers)
- no DHCPv6 support
- No good IPv6 support in IIS

Especially because of the missing DNS resolving over IPv6 you will not be able to run a IPv6-only Windows XP or Server 2003 machine. I have run Windows XP in an 'almost-IPv6-only' environment. If you provide a local DNS resolver that speaks IPv4 then you can get basic web browsing to work.

But as far as I am concerned it's not worth the trouble...

Comment: Ya, you are right. Even i had figured it out. Anyway thanks a lot. It is very difficult to find any sort of formal documentation on IPV6 on Win XP.

Comment: Windows XP and 2003 allow manual IPv6 address and route configuration via `netsh interface ipv6` starting with XPSP2 (and `ipv6` in earlier versions). I even have XP configured as an IPv6 *router* to Tunnelbroker. DNS servers can be added as well, but I haven't tested IPv6-only resolving.

Answer (score 2):

Go Properties on a network adapter. There is a list of protocols active on this adapter. Uncheck IPv4.

Comment: That does not help because if i do that, Both IPV4 and IPV6 get disabled. If i un-check only IPV4 and then use ipconfig to check the configuration, none of the addresses are shown, as opposed to windows vista, where id i un-check IPV4, i can see the IPV6 address.

Comment: Well I guess the answer is that you can't.